# How to show only the bibliography which is cited

Tags: bibliographies

I have a file called `paper.tex`. Another file called `PaperBib.bbl` contains all the bibliography for this. I've used `\cite{...}` to cite a paper and `\bibliography{PaperBib}` to print the references in the end of the document.

One problem is that currently all the papers in `PaperBib.bbl` are listed no matter whether they are cited or not. Is there a way to list:

- Only the ones which are cited?
- Only the ones which are not cited?

By the way, I have searched a little bit for similar questions. Someone suggested using `biblatex`, but I would prefer not to.

PS: I do not have `\nocite{*}` in either of these 2 files.

Comment: Search for `\nocite{*}` in your document and delete it.

Comment: Why would you prefer not to use bibtex? It is one of the best features of TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: @David Hammen: I think that SoftTimur doesn't want to use `biblatex`. He'd like to continue using `bibtex`.

Comment: because when i use biblatex, it says "biblatex.sty" can not be found... We share this tex file among several people, so I am afraid not all of them has installed biblatex completely.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Most probably you have `\nocite{*}` somewhere in the body of your document; this command will cause all entries of the chosen bibliographical database to be included in the list of references.

Simply delete `\nocite{*}` and re-compile your document (using, for example, `pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex`).

The `\nocite` command can also be used with a key-list as its argument; in this case, it will write the bibliographical information associated to the key-list (even if the publication(s) is(are) otherwise not cited) into the list of references.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really do not have `\notice{*}` in "paper.tex" or "paper.bbl".

Comment: @SoftTimur: It has to be (or had to be) somewhere. Try deleting the `.bbl` auxiliary file and processing again your document; if the problem persists, please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating your problem.

Comment: @SoftTimur Delte (almost) everything but the `.tex` file and `.bib` file. And run again, perhaps with `latexmk`. If you don't have `\nocite`, the only reason I can imagine is that you didn't run bibtex after updating the `.aux` file and therefore the `.bbl` file remains unchanged from previous run.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: i just realize that when i run `bibtex` the `.bbl` is cleaned... is it normal? I thought `.bbl` is written manually and should not be erased.

Comment: @Yan Zhou: You are right, but I do not see how `.bbl` is generated except manually writing it manually...

Comment: @SoftTimur: the file `.bbl` is generated automatically by `bibTeX`.

Comment: Actually, i just realize that it is `PaperBib.bib` which generates `Paper.bbl` by BibTeX. I just add `PaperBib.bib` to my folder, then BibTex runs successfully, then it only prints the cited works. Thank you all

Comment: The compilation queue works like this: Wherever (pdf)LaTeX finds `\cite` command it writes note into `.aux` file. Then bibTeX read this `.aux` file looking for `\cite` notes and (re)creates `.bbl` file with structure defined by bibliography style and containing only cited references (`\nocite` cites all referencies). Then (pdf)LaTeX again rewrites `.aux` file and includes `.bbl` file into document. Double compilation is mandatory because of making referencies right - all listof*s are reading old `.aux` and the correct one is made after compilation.

Answer (score 5):

@SoftTimur you must make sure that you are searching for `\nocite{*}` and NOT for `\notice{*}` this is a little late, but you consistently misspelled the command here ... so maybe you have `\nocite` in your document and are searching for `\notice` (which does not exist - is not a normal command).

Comment: Was this intended as a comment?  Admittedly people complain that too many answers are given as comments (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments) but I suppose it is a matter of style.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem that you are describing, and didn't have '\nocite{*}' anywhere in my document either.

I managed to fix this by deleting the files with the same name as the .tex file but with the following extensions:

- .aux
- .bbl
- .blg
- .log
- .pdf
- .synctex.gz

Comment: @Sveinung actually it provides a partial answer to the question, and the answer is perhaps better than the other three - the problem was that an old `bbl` file was used. Deleting the file, as suggested in this answer, is a step towards the solution. In the accepted answer this is not stated, although it is discussed in the comments. Instead the accepted answer only talks about `\nocite{*}`, which was not very relevant to the problem (although it may have been the cause if a previous version of the document contained `\nocite{*}` and the bibliography had not been recreated since).

Comment: @Marijn Thank you. I have upvoted the answer and deleted my comment. Hopefully, this will repair that I misunderstood of the answer.

Comment: Thank you - this solved it for me!

Answer (score 2):

The same issue  happened in TexStudio the following case. A bibliography.bib file in a top folder was used by main.tex files in subfolders, with the .tex files having the same name. Renaming solved the issue.

(PS Answered because couldn't comment yet.)